# PowerShell variable to batch issue

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am passing over a file dir to a batch file, the process works fine when no spaces in the dir, if I send the variable over to batch with space, it fails to pick up the whole dir path and stops at the frist space.

```bsh
function Get-WindowTitle($handle) {
    Get-Process |
        Where-Object { $_.MainWindowHandle -eq $handle } |
        Select-Object -Expand MainWindowTitle
}
$app = New-Object -COM 'Shell.Application'
$app.Windows() |
    Select-Object |
    select -ExpandProperty LocationURL -First 1 |
    Tee-Object -Variable dirvar

$dirvar1 = "$dirvar" -replace 'file:///', ''
$dirvar2 = "$dirvar1"-replace '%20', ' '
echo "$dirvar2"

Start-Process "C:\clean\varload-3.bat" "$dirvar2"
```

Comment: I see quotes around the variable so I am not sure what the problem could be.  You sure it is not a problem with the batch file?

Comment: I believe you'll need to send an escaped set of quotes so that when the BAT parses the argument, it doesn't it see multiples. Does this work? `Start-Process "C:\clean\varload-3.bat" "\`"$dirvar2\`""`

Comment: Thank you Ben that worked , i did work out a work around the issue, i will update my code to reflect this thanks again